# Jumping all over the place [Discrete Mathematics]

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

You are allowed to put a checker on any lattice point in the Cartesian plane with y-coordinate less than or equal to zero (i.e. a point with integer coordinates on or below the x-axis). Note that you may place infinitely many checkers to start.
The only legal moves are horizontal or vertical jumping--a checker can leap over a neighbor, ending up 2 units up, down, right, or left of its original position, provided that the destination point remains unoccupied. After the jump is complete, the checker that was jumped over is removed.
What is the minimum positive integral y-coordinate that a checker cannot attain?

**MyApproach:**

I think we have to solve this by Conway’s Soldier.

**Answer:**

5

*Any hint or other method to solve this problem*

Comment: Some key symbols seem to be missing in the body of the Question.  For example, in the first line "-coordinate" might be $y$-coordinate "less than or equal to $0$(?), so that this would explain "on or below the $x$-axis".  Please edit to supply the missing terms.  See [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for posting with mathematical expressions.

Comment: @hardmath I have edited it .Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: The solution is in one of Conway's books....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yeah but can you answer it ?

Comment: Ending up how many units above, below, to the right or to the left?

Comment: @WilliamElliot sorry it’s 2 units

Comment: @WilliamElliot if you find any more typos please let me know.

Comment: The proof is [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers).